# ElasticSearch : Query multiple value in array

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to put together a query/filter for elastic search. Here is what the structure look like

```
{
   _id:"0872300234",
   customers:[
      {
         name:"bob",
         priority:1,
         type:"GoodUser"
      },
      {
         name:"dan",
         priority:10,
         type:"BadUser"
      },
      {
         name:"sam",
         priority:10,
         type:"GoodUser"
      },
      {
         name:"cam",
         priority:2,
         type:"BadUser"
      }
   ]
}
```

So lets call this a "profile" document/record. I would like to find all the profiles that has a customer in that has a priority of 10 and is a "goodUser" (the same customer) so in the example sam will match but dan will not. I got a query that  gives me a profile where a customer has priority 10 and a customer(not the same one) has type GoodUser.

Is there a way to query a array item as a whole.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need nested types for that. More about nested objects you can find [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html) and the reason why you need them in situations where associations between nested fields is important. In your case, the mapping would need to look like this:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "profile": {
      "properties": {
        "customers": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "priority": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "type": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the query would need to be nested, as well:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "customers",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {"match": {
              "customers.type": "goodUser"
            }},
            {"term": {
              "customers.priority": {
                "value": 10
              }
            }}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```